# onHighlight in in AngularJS Typeahead

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

Is it possible to fire a callback when a user highlights a choice in the typeahead?

something like

```
typeahead-on-highlight='callback(highlightedValue)'
```

Comment: In the latest version of angular-ui-bootstrap, no, there is no directive for typeahead-on-highlight.  You are free to create one :)

Comment: Maybe I can put an onmouseover handler in the template for the typeahead...